# Is it a good practice to use DispatcherPriority with the UI thread dispatcher in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my WPF app, I have a lot of threads that occasionally need to update the UI.
When I need to update the UI elements, I need to perform a context switch from the back-end thread to the UI thread. I do that by the following code:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Send);
```

Basically, all the things that need to be performed on the UI thread are really quick, just a few milliseconds (update visibility, change color and etc).

My problem was that at some point the context switch took time, so I've solved it with collecting UI actions and then executing those actions with a single context switch.

Are there any improvements I can do via using a DispatcherPriority and what are some best practices in this matter?

I've read an article the recommends to use priority less than 7, which is NOT my case. I use DispatcherPriority.Send (which is 10)

> Now as a WPF programmer, we can push our custom time consuming logic into the queue maintained by the “Dispatcher” class and associate a lower priority value to that work item. Based on the value of priority field the corresponding code will be executed at the specified interval. Important thing to note here is that all the work is still being done by the UIthread, its just that with the help of DispatcherPriority we have prioritized our tasks. Ideally its recommended to give priority values less then 7(render) to the custom logic that we wish to execute with the help of Dispatcher.

https://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf

**Also, in general, is it a good practice to get involved in the execution priority of the ui thread queue?**

Comment: It's a good practice to *not* use `Invoke` at all, and use `async/await` for asynchronous operations. Updating the UI from a long running background thread/task/whatever should be done using the `IProgress<T>` interface and the `Progress<T>` implementation

Comment: In any case, MVVM means you *don't* do anything on the UI directly. To get the UI to update itself, modify the ViewModel properties and raise the PropertyChanged event. This will signal the UI to go get the new values from the VM instead of the other way round

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, we've already changed it to BeginInvoke (I've updated it in also in my question). I'm going to check out about the Progress interface, never heard of it. Thank you!

Comment: @DimaK trying to modify the UI from background code breaks the MVVM pattern and simply isn't needed in WPF. Let data binding update the UI when the viewmodel data changes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My view model is registered to an event that is raised by a back end thread. When I get to the listener in the view model, I'm in the context of the back-end thread. So, I switch to the Ui Thread via BeginInvoke and add an item to my observable collection that has a binding to the items-source of a data grid in my xaml. If I don't do that, I will get an exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".